# Bash add characters before and after $foo

Tags: bash

So if I have

```
$foo = foo
```

I would like to add `:` at the beginning and `!` at the end. I tried the below:

```
bar=$( ":" $foo "!" )
```

Comment: You can use `":$foo"'!'` (see e.g. https://superuser.com/a/301330/370326), but `$foo = foo` looks suspicious.

Comment: Please add bash version to your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `bar=$( ":" $foo "!" )`, with this command you try to assign the result of `:foo!` command to your variable. You will probably get an output like `:foo!: command not found` and your $bar variable will be not set.

You can use :

```
foo=foo
bar=':'$foo'!'
echo $bar 
# Will return :foo!
```

Comment: `$(echo something)` is generally an antipattern -- the `echo` and `$( )` mostly cancel each other out, except that it's less efficient (it requires creating a subprocess to do the `echo`) and has a bunch of possible parsing weirdnesses. BTW, `echo $(something)` is also bad for similar reasons.

Comment: Ok thanks i didn't knew that. I will remove this options of my answer thanks a lot !

Comment: `bar=":$foo!"` should be enough

Answer (score 0):

the builtin printf can do that also but I'm not sure if it is portable solution.

```
foo=foo
printf -v bar ":$foo!"
echo "$bar"
```

see

```
help printf
```

or

```
man printf
```